# Why do ios need restart for bold settings?

Tags: ios, text

Why there is a restart required for changing the text boldness in iOS? For text size there is no such requirement, why only for test boldness?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking why Apple made a discussion leads to opinions. If you can rephrase this to be "since apple decided to do X, how can I do Y?" It will be easy to see if there is a practical problem to be solved objectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a restart but rather a respring. All that happens is the SpringBoard is restarted, not the actual device rebooting. This is because the bold text option changes the text displayed by the SpringBoard, unlike the text size.